# Share .exe without getting warnings on download

Tags: c#, .net, windows

We have finally completed the first market-ready version of our product (MS-Word Plugin). We've sent the download link (.exe hosted on AWS S3) out to our potential clients, but apparently most of them get security warning when visiting the download site and therefore won't download anything.

We've already sent our installer for inspection to Microsoft hoping to get validated for Edge, but I assume the process will take a few weeks.

What instant solutions are there? We've already thought of sharing a dropbox link, but we would like to have sth. more professional. **We really appreciate any feedback since our situation is more than sub-optimal**

Comment: You're essentially asking how to tell your client's anti-virus (including those built into the browser) that your exe isn't a virus.

Comment: So it's not the browser alone... And how would we go about that?

Comment: +Do you know any (temporary) workaround maybe?

Comment: Buy a code signing certificate and sign your build

Comment: The best will be to certify your application, but it will take some time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/win_cert/windows-certification-portal

Comment: @D.Kastier What amount of time are we talking about here?

Comment: That I do not known... But I guess that it can take from a couple weeks to a month

Comment: Here says it is faster: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/publish/publish-your-app/app-certification-process?pivots=store-installer-msix

Comment: But to make sure: This will also remove the warnings on download? It seems to me that this is just for the installation process

Comment: You might want to hire an actual security expert. You're stepping into quite the rabbit hole here.

Comment: The instant solution is to sign your exe and plugin with your own generated root and dev certificate and then send your customers the public certificate chain so they can add those to their trusted certificate store. Browsers will still be careful and show a warning but beyond that it might just work. Do note that by doing this you do put the security of the systems of your potential clients at risk. For example if you leak the private keys: https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2023/05/leak-of-msi-uefi-signing-keys-stokes-concerns-of-doomsday-supply-chain-attack/